# Ansible playbook with pbrun not working

Tags: linux, ansible

first-playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: test
      shell: chdir=/home/tibco pbrun su - tibco sh test.sh
      sudo: yes
```

error:

```
[root@c0043724 ansible]# ansible-playbook -vvv first-playbook.yml -u balp --ask-pass -c paramiko
SSH password:

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: balp on PORT 22 TO c0043725.itcs.hp.com
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531409.47-88648204897709 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531409.47-88648204897709 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531409.47-88648204897709'
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> PUT /tmp/tmpNP2qY2 TO /home/balp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531409.47-88648204897709/setup
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/balp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531409.47-88648204897709/setup; rm -rf /home/balp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531409.47-88648204897709/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
ok: [c0043725.itcs.hp.com]

TASK: [test] ******************************************************************
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: balp on PORT 22 TO c0043725.itcs.hp.com
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> REMOTE_MODULE command chdir=/home/tibco pbrun su - tibco sh test.sh #USE_SHELL
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531412.61-87821666758998 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531412.61-87821666758998 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531412.61-87821666758998'
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> PUT /tmp/tmpNgfy06 TO /home/balp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531412.61-87821666758998/command
<c0043725.itcs.hp.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=torjbeltprhcmjkqbwcakmroqrxvfiai] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c "echo BECOME-SUCCESS-torjbeltprhcmjkqbwcakmroqrxvfiai; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/balp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531412.61-87821666758998/command; rm -rf /home/balp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1426531412.61-87821666758998/ >/dev/null 2>&1"'
failed: [c0043725.itcs.hp.com] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "pbrun su - tibco sh test.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.024944", "end": "2015-03-16 18:43:33.371752", "rc": 127, "start": "2015-03-16 18:43:33.346808", "warnings": []}
stderr: /bin/sh: pbrun: command not found

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/first-playbook.retry

c0043725.itcs.hp.com       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Can you please help to fix ?

Comment: The output shows "command not found".  What happens if you specify the full path to the pbrun command?

Comment: If i am using like                                                                                                     command: /opt/pb/bin/pbrun su - tibco                                                       ;then it is strucked

Comment: what does "strucked" mean? can you run `sudo pbrun su - tibco sh test.sh` by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Need more info for better debugging. But my guess would be you're trying to mix 3 different ways of doing su.

- some custom tool called pbrun (I'm guessing it's some script created by you/your ops ppl to allow you sudo access).
- `su` in the command you're executing.
- You are asking ansible to su by specifying `sudo: yes`.
- (not to mention the fact that you're running playbook as `root`, which would implicitly connect as root to remote machine by default (unless you overrode it somewhere in configuration or inventory) rendering `sudo`ing unnecessary in the first place)

I recommend you use full path to `pbrun` and `test.sh` in your playbook and retain only one way to do `su` of the three.

-- edit --

I assume you already know abt `sudo_exe` parameter in [ansible.cfg](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#sudo-exe)

```
# change this for alternative sudo implementations
sudo_exe = sudo
```